# Stop a moving Python turtle when it's close to another turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

How do I stop a randomly moving turtle using a `while` loop when it comes with 50 units of another turtle?

I have one turtle that randomly selects a location and creates a large dot or hole, and another turtle that moves around randomly making 90 degree turns and moving forward 50 units every time. The randomly moving turtle stops when it goes off of the end of the screen, but how do I also make the turtle stop when it gets to the hole created by the other turtle?

```
import random
import turtle

def turtlesClose(t1, t2):
    if t1.distance(t2)<50:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isInScreen(win,turt):
    leftBound = -win.window_width() / 2
    rightBound = win.window_width() / 2
    topBound = win.window_height() / 2
    bottomBound = -win.window_height() / 2

    turtleX = turt.xcor()
    turtleY = turt.ycor()

    stillIn = True
    if turtleX > rightBound or turtleX < leftBound:
        stillIn = False
    if turtleY > topBound or turtleY < bottomBound:
        stillIn = False
    return stillIn

def main():
    wn = turtle.Screen()
    # Define your turtles here
    june = turtle.Turtle()
    july = turtle.Turtle()

    july.shape('turtle')
    july.up()
    july.goto(random.randrange(-250, 250, 1), random.randrange(-250, 250, 1))
    july.down()
    july.dot(100)

    june.shape('turtle')
    while isInScreen(wn,june):
        coin = random.randrange(0, 2)
        dist = turtlesClose(july, june)
        if coin == 0:
            june.left(90)
        else:
            june.right(90)
        june.forward(50)

        if dist == 'True':
            break

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is this statement:

```
if dist == 'True':
```

You don't want quotes around `True`. Although this will work:

```
if dist == True:
```

The correct way to express this is:

```
if dist is True:
```

or better yet:

```
if dist:
```

Otherwise your code seems to work.  Below's a rewrite taking advantage of some turtle idioms and other code cleanup:

```
from random import randrange, choice
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def turtlesClose(t1, t2):
    return t1.distance(t2) < 50

def isInScreen(window, turtle):
    leftBound = -window.window_width() / 2
    rightBound = window.window_width() / 2
    topBound = window.window_height() / 2
    bottomBound = -window.window_height() / 2

    turtleX, turtleY = turtle.position()

    return leftBound < turtleX < rightBound and bottomBound < turtleY < topBound

def main():
    screen = Screen()

    july = Turtle('circle')
    july.shapesize(100 / CURSOR_SIZE)

    july.up()
    july.goto(randrange(-250, 250), randrange(-250, 250))
    july.down()

    june = Turtle('turtle')

    while isInScreen(screen, june):

        if turtlesClose(july, june):
            break

        turn = choice([june.left, june.right])

        turn(90)

        june.forward(50)

main()
```